# Json.NET JsonConvert.DeserializeObject()

Tags: c#, jsonconvert

- ***how can i get the "Points" value using JsonConvert.DeserializeObject can anyone help me***

  {
  "data":
  {
  "Gamers": [
  {
  "id": "5397742571",
  "startTime": "Thu, 28 Jun 2022 00:04:13 GMT",
  "points": 11.647601,
  "hash": {
  "id": "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "hash": "xxxxxxxxxx",
  "__typename": "GamerRace"
  },
  }
  ] }

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Well, would recommend using tools such as [json2csharp](https://json2csharp.com/) to convert the JSON to C# classes.

Comment: Why did you tag this question with [api] when the API tag description states: _"DO NOT USE. Use specific tags like [google-cloud-platform], [facebook], [amazon-web-services] instead or [api-design] where applicable. Questions asking to recommend or find an API are off-topic."_ ? Also, none of those seem like they would be relevant to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all. Your json have some issue. I fix it and here is it.

```
  {
  "data": {
           "Gamers": [
             { 
                "id": "5397742571",
                "startTime": "Thu, 28 Jun 2022 00:04:13 GMT",
                "points": 11.647601,
                "hash": {
                   "id": "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
                   "hash": "xxxxxxxxxx",
                   "__typename": "GamerRace"
                 }
              }
            ]
        }
    }
```

Now Create Model for this json like below.

```
public class Data
{
    public List<Gamer> Gamers { get; set; }
}

public class Gamer
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string startTime { get; set; }
    public double points { get; set; }
    public Hash hash { get; set; }
}

public class Hash
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string hash { get; set; }
    public string __typename { get; set; }
}
```

Now its time to convert your json into c# object.

```
Data people = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Data>(yourJson);
```

Hope it helps you buddy.